# how to get json data from api in listview paging

Tags: xamarin.forms, syncfusion

i want to get data from web api in listview with paging. What i have done so far i dont see any problem in my code but i am getting null values in Handle_OnDemandLoading

```
 private FeaturedItemList products = new FeaturedItemList();  
        protected async void FeaturedList()
        {

   var httpClient = new HttpClient();


                        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://orangepotato.rjcpacking.com/index.php?route=api/login/getFeaturedProducts");


                        products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeaturedItemList>(json);

                        dataPager.Source = products.products;



        }  
void  Handle_OnDemandLoading(object sender, Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.DataPager.OnDemandLoadingEventArgs e)
        {
            var source= products.products.Skip(e.StartIndex).Take(e.PageSize);
            FeaturedlistView.ItemsSource = source.AsEnumerable();// here is i am getting null values but i am getting values in datapager.source
        }
```

Comment: are you sure products.products contains data?  and source?  First you need to figure out exactly which element is null - use the debugger to do this

Comment: Put debugger on products.products and check whether it contains data